# Column of matrix in general position

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean when the columns of a matrix are in general position given that the matrix is underdetermined?

Comment: More context would be helpful here, e.g. the sentence(s) where you read this.

Comment: i didn't get u!!

Comment: Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position) says about "general position".  In the case of the columns of an $n \times m$ matrix in linear algebra, "general position" should imply that the columns are linearly independent if that is possible, and no square submatrix is singular.

Answer (score 0):

i would guess, that a matrix created by these columns are in upper-triangular shape, but there are zero-lines at the bottom. Hence, we can clearly see, that system is underdetermined.